# How to calculate percentages using Pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 users s1 who has 10 dollars, s2 10,20 dollars, and s3 20,20,30 dollars. I want to calculate percentage of users who had 10, 20 and 30 dollars. Is my interpretation correct here?

input

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = (pd.DataFrame({'users': ['s1', 's2', 's2', 's3', 's3', 's3'],
              'dollars': [10,10,20,20,20,30]}))
```

output

```
% of subjects who had 10 dollors        0.4
% of subjects who had 20 dollors        0.4
% of subjects who had 30 dollors        0.2
```

tried

```
df1.groupby(['dollars']).agg({'dollars': 'sum'}) / df1['dollars'].sum() * 100
```

Comment: Can you explain how count first `0.4` ?

Comment: I interpreted like this. Users who had 10 dollars are 2 (s1 and s2) and total users are 3. I divided 2/3 = 0.66. I repeated the same with other and took the sum (1.66). Finally divided 0.66 with 1.66 = 0.4.

Comment: I solved it but I am doubtful if this is the right answer. ```df2 = df1.drop_duplicates().groupby(['dollars']).count()
df2.reset_index()
df3 = df2['users']/len(df2.index)
df3 = df3.reset_index()
df3['percentage'] = df3['users']/df3['users'].sum()```

Comment: Do you want `pd.crosstab(df1['users'], df1['dollars']).gt(0).mean().mul(100)`? This doesn't give the 0.4 though

Comment: @mozway yes, it gives the percentage and then I normalize this to the total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the percentage of users that have each kind of bill you can use a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
out = pd.crosstab(df1['users'], df1['dollars']).gt(0).mean().mul(100)
```

output:

```
dollars
10    66.666667
20    66.666667
30    33.333333
dtype: float64
```

If you want normalized counts:

```
out/out.sum()
```

Output:

```
dollars
10    0.4
20    0.4
30    0.2
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Note that you can also easily get the count for "at least N bills", "exactly 1 bill", "no bill", etc. by changing the condition (`gt(N)`/`eq(1)`/`eq(0)`)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) for count unique `users` per `dollars`, divide number of unique `dollars` and last divide `sum`:

```
out = df1.groupby('dollars')['users'].nunique().div(df1['dollars'].nunique())
out = out / out.sum()

print (out)
dollars
10    0.4
20    0.4
30    0.2
Name: users, dtype: float64
```